# How should I set up a camera for monitor my baby?

Tags: electrical, wiring, wifi

I have a closet which is big , with window and in the master bedroom. So I want to set up as baby room. There are two ceiling lights only. There is no power outlet.

If I want to set up a wifi camera, I need to get the power from the ceiling lights. The light bulbs are mounted horizontal so I cannot buy a light bulb wifi cam.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your question is a little too broad. You may be able to drop an outlet from a light switch or outlet on the opposing side of the bedroom wall, but we really can't help with so little information.

Answer (score 2):

For a cheap and dirty solution, you can get a light bulb socket that contains a power outlet, e.g., [here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-2-Outlet-Socket-Adapter-Beige-or-Cream-54178/203750637). If the camera uses a USB for power, you could try [this DIY solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3rwWYS6xac).

If you want it neat and tidy, then put in a new power outlet on the wall, either routing the power cable through the wall (requires identifying a suitable place from which to pull the cable: may be relatively easy if you have a basement or attic from which you can access the closet walls above/below), or over the wall in a conduit.